# which class need to be addressed to support drag'n drop between Qt app and finder

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm trying to build an app which list the folders and files from an Android device to finder and be able copy from/to PC.

I have done the class as below in my Browser.cpp

```
Browser::Browser(USBDevice dev, QWidget *parent) :
     QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    USBDevice MyDevice;

    MyDevice = dev;

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

    window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("PULS"));
    window->resize(600, 600);
    // window->setDragEnabled(true);
    //   window->setAcceptDrops(true);
    //   window->setMouseTracking(true);



    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(window);

    QPushButton* CreateFolderButton = new QPushButton("Create Folder", centralWidget);
    CreateFolderButton->setFixedSize(100,20);
    //QVBoxLayout* Layout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
    //Layout->addWidget(CreateFolderButton);

    QPushButton* DeleteButton = new QPushButton("Delete", centralWidget);
    DeleteButton->setFixedSize(100,20);
    QVBoxLayout* Layout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
    Layout->addWidget(CreateFolderButton);
    Layout->addWidget(DeleteButton);

    QTreeWidget *MyTree = new QTreeWidget(centralWidget);
    Layout->addWidget(MyTree);
    MyTree->setSortingEnabled(true);
    MyTree->setColumnWidth(0, 400);
    MyTree->setDragDropMode(DragDrop);
    MyTree->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    MyTree->setDragEnabled(true);
    MyTree->setMouseTracking(true);

    QTreeWidgetItem* headerItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    headerItem->setText(0,QString("File Name"));
    headerItem->setText(1,QString("Size (Bytes)"));
    headerItem->setText(2,QString("Date"));
    MyTree->setHeaderItem(headerItem);

    Recursive_Parse(MyTree, MyDevice.device_id, MyDevice.device_id->storage, 0, 0, 0);

    window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    MyButtonGroup* group = new MyButtonGroup(MyTree, MyDevice, MyDevice.device_id, MyDevice.device_id->storage, centralWidget);
    group->addButton(CreateFolderButton);
    group->addButton(DeleteButton);

    window->show();
}
```

and the class in browser.h as

```
class Browser : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Browser(USBDevice dev, QWidget* parent = 0);    
        void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
        void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
        void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
        void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
        ~Browser(){};
};
```

Drag'n drop is working in the Tree I can move stuff even if it's not working properly as I can drop a file on a file and create a child. By file, I just mean the TreeWidgetItem not the real file. This is also something I need to add but I do not know where.

But I do not see how to handle the dran'ndrop. I need to be able to control the drag'n drop inside the tree and outside to copy file from/to my computer.

It seems that :

```
        void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
        void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
        void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
        void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
```

Are never called... even if the drag'n drop works

Any idea how to handle event and overload or customised the behaviour ?

Thanks

Comment: why a -1 ??? I have removed my previous post with a similar question but with less details 6sec after this post

Answer (score 0):

The class that has the `dragEnterEvent` and stuff overridden is named `Browser`, however you do not instantiate it, instead you instantiate `QTreeWidget`:

```
QTreeWidget *MyTree = new QTreeWidget(centralWidget);
```

So that is the reason why no members from `Browser` will get called. You perhaps wanted to write:

```
QTreeWidget *MyTree = new Browser(MyDevice, centralWidget);
```

Or something like that.

Comment: How to make it ? Sorry I'm newby

Comment: Browser is mostly the class who design the overall app : button, tree... and the TreeWidget used to display data.

Comment: Your complaint was that the member functions  of Browser are not called. Indeed these are not when you drag and drop in something else. If Browser is entirely meant for something else then derive some other MyTreeWidget class from QTreeWidget, override dragEnterEvent et all of it and instantiate it.

Comment: this was my thought. Do what I have done to create browser for TreeWidget.

Comment: Sorry for these stupid question but I'm new in C++/Qt and have a very tiny deadline to learn, develop and deliver

Comment: No need to be sorry. C++ language and Qt framework are big and complex. It is extremely unlikely to learn to use effectively with short deadline.